# Mule HTTP Connector - session is required to access resource

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

I have requirement to develop mule flow to access, login, navigate and then submit form (HTTPS Post). I am using HTTP Connector configured as HTTPS with all required configurations like host/port/path/method/TSL etc. Added Query parameters which I tracked from HTTP trace in Firefox. Also set cookies as Header but I am getting **A session is required to access this resource.** response instead login to application.

Please find below HTTP Connector and configuration

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to set cookies explicitly, and also setting them as HTTP headers will not work. First find out the type of authentication required by the service (basic, oauth, other?), then try to configure it in the HTTP connector.